# SQL Developer query record is copied into the single excel cell?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, copy-paste

I am using SQL developer (version 4.1.3.20).

Recently I have begun to have a problem with copy and paste.

When I copy and paste my query result to an Excel spreadsheet, no matter how many columns are in my record it's being pasted into one cell.

For example:

I have 3 columns in my SQL record i.e `name`, `date` and `amount`.
When copied to the Excel file, it is pasted into single cell like this:
`namedateamount` in `A1`.

What I want is columns are copied into consecutive cells: `Name` in `A1`, `Date` in `B1`, `Amount` in `C1` and their values into `A2`, `B2`, `C2`, and so on...

How can I overcome this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to a more recent SQL Developer version (17.4, currently). I've just tested it, works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+A

Ctrl+Shift+C

alt-tab to Excel

Ctrl+V...that should give you all all of the current page of results, plus the column headers.

If that doesn't work, right-click on the grid, choose 'Export...', then choose format 'Excel 2003+ (XLSX)', supply a filename, and you'll get a new file name.

You can also choose to export your results to CSV to the clipboard - this will be handy when you want to copy and paste the ENTIRE RESULTSET for a query to Excel vs just what's shown in the data grid.

If all this fails, try an application restart, something 'fishy' is going on. If that still fails, listen to @littlefoot and get a more recent copy of SQL Developer where you'll get much better support.